# eval echo "$line" ignoring '&' symbol

Tags: bash

I am using the below portion in my script to replace variables in a file.

But after running this portion of the script , the "&" symbol is ignored by the script. Is there a reason for this behaviour ?

```
 while read line
   do
   eval  echo "$line" >> output.txt
   done < "input"
```

My input file looks like below

```
XXX.6.ID=LCPR_PROJ&
XXX.6.VALUE=$PMS&
XXX.6.CTID=58&
XXX.6.ECID=1032&
XXX.6.SEC=
```

After running the command , my output looks like below

```
XXX.6.ID=LCPR_PROJ
XXX.6.VALUE=132
XXX.6.CTID=58
XXX.6.ECID=1032
XXX.6.SEC=
```

Do I need to alter something in my command ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to use `eval`!

`eval` will evaluate the expression separately, and interpret the `&` character.

The `&` character tells bash to run the command in a subshell. From the [Bash man page](http://hacktux.com/man/bash):

> If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell.

Remove it from your script

```
while read line
  do
    echo "$line" >> output.txt
  done < "input"
```

and it will work as expected.

If you *do* want to run every line through `eval`, and you know what you're doing, then you will have to manually detect and escape the `&`s:

```
while read line; do
  line=${line/&/\\&}
  eval echo "$line";
done
```

By using [bash's string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).